# Spree command not found

Tags: spree

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Have successfully managed to create new storefront using the command:

rails g spree:install

But whenever I try to use the command 'spree' in the command line I get the error:

'command not found: spree'

This is proving problematic for creating extensions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Forgot to rehash rbenv.

Comment: same issue for me too ;)